# Story about a woman cursed to be cold all the time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find this short story I read in high school. I believe it was written by Isaac Asimov since I was writing a paper on him at the time I read it. The only thing I can remember about the story is that there was a woman who was married. And something happened to her, a curse of some sort, that made her feel cold all the time. Eventually her husband's warmth is no longer enough for her so she begins to search for a warmth that will. And she keeps going through guy after guy moving on once their warmth isn't enough anymore. If any one knows this story I would love to find it again.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of us know when you were in high school. Was it last year? 50 years ago? Did you read this as part of an anthology, or was it published separately?

Comment: I can't say I've read all of Asimov's fiction - that would be more or less impossible - but this doesn't sound like any Asimov story that I can recall, nor does the summary sound like an Asimov plot.

Comment: @JonKiparsky - Asimov did edit several SciFi anthologies (and there's a SciFi magazine with his name on it) so perhaps that's the cause of the confusion?

Comment: Could you please give us more details about the book? Try to put a summary in the title to attract more experts to your question.

Comment: @SystemDown I think you're probably right.

Answer (score 15):

["Baby, It's Cold Outside"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42162) by Isaac Asimov.

http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story011.html

Copied from the above link...

> *A cold, calculating woman who married for money only and to whom cash alone has worth is transformed by Azazel into someone who desperately
> craves the warmth of a male body—any body.*

Part of the Azazel series.  Main character has a small demon (Azazel) which helps him solve other people's problems, but never in the way he wants or expects.

The lady in question mentions that she had tried other men (losing count at 15-17), but none brought her the warmth that her husband did.